# Converting Hand Written DI to Windsor Provided DI

Tags: c#-4.0, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, factory, factory-pattern

For the past six or seven months I have been doing DI in some of my components as result they have grown to become little bit of complicated. In the past I have been creating Object graphs with hand written Factories. Since it is becoming unmanageable I am trying to move that code to Framework dependent DI(by code and not by some XML files). I am posting my Code as well as issues I am stuck with.

Here is my composition layer (it is big, so bear with me :) ):

```
    IAgentFactory GetAgentFactory()
    {
        string errorMessage;
        IDictionary<AgentType, ServiceParameters> agentFactoryPrerequisite = new Dictionary<AgentType, ServiceParameters>();
        string restResponseHeaderStatus = MyConfigurationProject.GetConfigValue("RestResponseHeaderStatus", out errorMessage);


        var service1Parameters = new ServiceParameters();
        service1Parameters.BindingName = MyConfigurationProject.GetConfigValue("Service1WebHttpBindingConfiguration", out errorMessage).ToString();
        service1Parameters.HeaderPassword = MyConfigurationProject.GetConfigValue("Service1HeaderPassword", out errorMessage).ToString();
        service1Parameters.HeaderUserName = MyConfigurationProject.GetConfigValue("Service1HeaderUserName", out errorMessage).ToString();
        service1Parameters.ResponseHeaderStatus = restResponseHeaderStatus;
        service1Parameters.ServicePassword = MyConfigurationProject.GetConfigValue("Service1ServicePassword", out errorMessage).ToString();
        service1Parameters.ServiceUrl = MyConfigurationProject.GetConfigValue("Service1URL", out errorMessage).ToString();
        service1Parameters.ServiceUserName = MyConfigurationProject.GetConfigValue("Service1ServiceUserName", out errorMessage).ToString();
        agentFactoryPrerequisite.Add(new KeyValuePair<AgentType, ServiceParameters>(AgentType.Service1, service1Parameters));

        var agentFactory = new AgentFactory(agentFactoryPrerequisite);
        return agentFactory;
    }

    protected DatalayerSettings GetDataLayerSettings()
    {
        var datalayerSettings = new DatalayerSettings();
        datalayerSettings.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        datalayerSettings.MySchemaName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyDatabaseSchema"];
        datalayerSettings.UpdatingUser = "Admin";
        return datalayerSettings;
    }



    PostgersDAFactory GetPostGresDaFactory()
    {
        var datalayerSettings = GetDataLayerSettings();
        return new PostgersDAFactory(datalayerSettings, "MyAssembly.PostgresDA", "MyDifferentAssembly.CommonDatalayer", "MyServiceLogPath");
    }



    public class PostgersDAFactory
    {
        readonly DatalayerSettings _datalayerSettings;
        readonly string _assemblyName;
        readonly string _logPath;
        readonly string _mySecondAssemblyName;
        public PostgersDAFactory(DatalayerSettings datalayerSettings, string assemblyName, string mySecondAssemblyName, string logPath)
        {
            _datalayerSettings = datalayerSettings;
            _assemblyName = assemblyName;
            _logPath = logPath;
            _commonDaAssemblyName = commonDaAssemblyName;
        }

        public IDA1 GetDA1Instance()
        {
            var type1 = Type.GetType("MyAssembly.PostgresDA.ClassRealisingImplementation_For_DA1," + _assemblyName);
            return (IDA1)Activator.CreateInstance(type1, _datalayerSettings, _logPath);
        }

        public IDA2 GetDA2Instance()
        {
            var type1 = Type.GetType("MyAssembly.PostgresDA.ClassRealisingImplementation_For_DA2," + _assemblyName);
            return (IDA2)Activator.CreateInstance(type1, _datalayerSettings);
        }

        public IDA3 GetDA3Instance()
        {
            var type1 = Type.GetType("MyAssembly2.ClassRealisingImplementation_For_DA3," + _commonDaAssemblyName);
            return (IDA3)Activator.CreateInstance(type1, _datalayerSettings);
        }

    }



    public BaseFileHandler GetFileHandler(FileProvider fileprovider, MockedServiceCalculator mockedServicecalculator = null)
    {
        string errorMessage;
        var postgresFactory = GetPostGresDaFactory();
        var Da1Instance = postgresFactory.GetDA1Instance();
        var fileSyncBusiness = new FileSyncBusiness(Da1Instance);
        var interfaceConfiguratonParameters = fileSyncBusiness.GetInterfaceConfigurationParameters();
        var servicePointDetailsSettings = new ServicePointDetailsSettings();
        var nullDate = new DateTime(2099, 1, 1);

        CommonValidations commonValidations;
        if (mockedServicecalculator == null)
        {
            commonValidations = GetStubbedCommonValidations(nullDate);
        }
        else
        {
            commonValidations = GetCommonValidations_WithMockedServiceCalculator(nullDate, mockedServicecalculator);
        }

        switch (fileprovider)
        {
            case FileProvider.Type1:
                var type1Adapter = new Type1Adaptor(false, nullDate);
                servicePointDetailsSettings = GetUtiltaParameters(interfaceConfiguratonParameters);
                return new Type1FileHandler(servicePointDetailsSettings, fileSyncBusiness, commonValidations, type1Adapter);

            case FileProvider.Type2:
                var type2Adapter = new Type2Adaptor(true, nullDate);
                servicePointDetailsSettings.ApplicableParameters = MyApplicationCommonMethods.ConvertConfigurationTableToDictonary(interfaceConfiguratonParameters, "applicableintype2");
                servicePointDetailsSettings.BadFileLocation = MyConfigurationProject.GetConfigValue("Type2BadFileLocation", out errorMessage);
                servicePointDetailsSettings.DateFormat = MyConfigurationProject.GetConfigValue("Type2DateFormat", out errorMessage);
                servicePointDetailsSettings.FailureFileLocation = MyConfigurationProject.GetConfigValue("Type2FailureFile", out errorMessage);

                servicePointDetailsSettings.LogFileName = "Type2LogFile";
                servicePointDetailsSettings.LogPath = MyConfigurationProject.GetConfigValue("Type2ErrorLog", out errorMessage);
                servicePointDetailsSettings.MandatoryParameters = MyApplicationCommonMethods.GetDictonaryForMandatoryParameters(interfaceConfiguratonParameters, "applicableintype2", "mandatoryintype2");
                servicePointDetailsSettings.SourceFileLocation = MyConfigurationProject.GetConfigValue("type2FileLocation", out errorMessage);
                servicePointDetailsSettings.SuccessFileLocation = MyConfigurationProject.GetConfigValue("type2SuccessFile", out errorMessage);
                servicePointDetailsSettings.TargetFileExtension = MyConfigurationProject.GetConfigValue("type2SupportedFileType", out errorMessage);
                servicePointDetailsSettings.Type2RecordTag = MyConfigurationProject.GetConfigValue("MyApplicationtype2RecordTag", out errorMessage);

                return new Type2FileHandler(servicePointDetailsSettings, fileSyncBusiness, commonValidations, type2Adapter);
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException("FileProvider type: " + Convert.ToInt32(fileprovider) + " is not implemented");
        }
    }
    }
```

While moving towards Windsor, I am facing several issues, as I have never used this product, it seems it is very complicated.

**Issues:**

1. How to pass parameters to object when they have parameterised
   constructors?
2. I know there is a better way to write this "PostgersDAFactory"
   class, but simply don't know.
3. There are some Factory methods Such as GetAgentFactory(), which are
   dependent on some static method of other project, which in turn
   gives me configuration values(I ahd to store them in the database),
   another method GetDataLayerSettings is dependent on app config as
   well as some static string.
4. I am likely to change parameter names in my classes in order to
   promote readability, so how to turn on the logging for Windsor?
5. Finally another complicated method GetFileHandler, has some logic
   (switch case).

I have tried going on there website but I found it totally difficult to digest information, there API is huge and learning curve seems to be mammoth.

**Note:** I had to change the variable names due to security reasons.

Comment: Why do you want to move to use a DI Container you don't know? You say that your code is becoming unmanageable, but why do you expect it to become manageable by moving from something you *do* know, to something you *don't* know?

Comment: @MarkSeemann It is my assumption that may be my code will become a little compact by using a Container.

Comment: It most likely will not: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer

Comment: @MarkSeemann Thanks for the great article. It seems that I won't be getting any real value in terms of maintainability by switching to DI framework. However, I think that there can be kind of Hybrid approach where all of the code is Poor Man's DI and part of the code (PostgresDA Factory) can be moved to more of Convention based ? If Yes then probably You can guide me how to do that with Windsor